# Como puedo usar el valor de una variable con LINQ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, linq, datatable

Estoy tratando de asignar una variable a un select usando LINQ.

Mi funcion lo que hace que evalua un data set para obtener el SourceID segun el caption que se le haya pasado adentro del select.

Lo que intento de hacer es a partir de una aplicacion en Windows Forms. El usuario cuando entre el valor de este caption en un textBox, este valor pueda ser remplazado por el valor ya existente del LINQ.

Aqui esta mi funcion:

```
private string GetMappingTable()
{
    string SourceID = "";

    var ds = GetMappingTable();
    foreach (DataTable dst in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dst.Rows)
        {
            var DataSourceId = ds.Tables["Table"]
            .Select("Caption = 'testUSers'")
            .Select(r => r["SourceID"]) 
            .Where(s => s != DBNull.Value)
            .Select(s => s.ToString()) 
            .FirstOrDefault();

            SourceID = DataSourceId;
        }
    }
    return SourceID;
}
```

Deseo que donde dice `.Select("Caption = 'testUSers'")` el usuario a partir del texBox pueda entrar otro caption y ese pueda ser remplazado.

Ejemplo:

En el select dice 'testUsers', si el usuario decide de poner Users. Este deberia ponerse en el valor del caption donde dice testUsers.

De que forma podria hacer eso?

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero que puedes hacer es que la función GetMappingTable() reciba un parámetro, que seria la entrada del usuario.

```
private string GetMappingTable(string texto)
```

Luego para reemplazar el valor dentro de la función puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
.Select(String.Format("Caption = '{0}'",texto))
```

O de esta otra forma

```
.Select("Caption = '" + texto + "'")
```

Comment: funciono perfectamente de las 2 formas! muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

lo que tienes que hacer es que en lugar de escribir el testUSers de forma predeterminada manejalo como una variable tipo String dentro del método GetMappingTable(), y en el método .Select concatenas esa variable de la siguiente manera:
.Select("Caption = '" + texto + "'")

Así obtendras un cambio en el "texto" cada que modifiques el contenido de tu variable.
Saludos